# How to create a multiline response in one message from json in microsoft bot composer?

Tags: botframework, bot-framework-composer

I have a [web api](https://parsalotfy.ir/api/people) which gives me a list of people.

This is the list, requested it in Postman :

[image: List of people]

In my bot, I want to show this list to the user in **ONE message**.

When I use `foreach` it sends a message for each person.

Here is the bot composer :

[image]

And here is the result :

[image]

Following picture is what I expect : (hardcoded)

[image]

How can I do this **in composer** ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use something like this (this is for an order but it's conceptually the same) in the output templates:

a template to format each item:

````
# orderItem(x)
- ```
- ${x.name} ${x.qty}
```
````

And then the template for the order:

````
# OrderDetails
- ```
ORDER: **${dialog.order.number}**

${join(select(dialog.order.items, x => orderItem(x)), '\n')}

```
````

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I was testing it... man you are the John skeet of microsoft bot framework :D I didn't even know this feature exist. Thank you , It worked the way I expected.

Comment: ha ha ha, uff, no way, glad to help 